# Upload .m3u8 from another domain

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I upload a playlist through a series of redirects from one domain to another for Tizen webapis.avplay. The app provides navigation redirecton, but not losing the playlist. If you request a playlist from one domain, it works correctly.
My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="my_id_app" version="1.0.0" height="720" width="1280" viewmodes="fullscreen">
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
    <tizen:application id="***.Basicapplication" package="***" required_version="2.3"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="icon106.png"/>
    <name>app_name</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/avplay"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/productinfo"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.audio"/>
    <tizen:profile name="tv"/>
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape" context-menu="disable" background-support="enable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Please tell me how to make the application play a playlist?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the cookies, which the player did not send. Fixed it with webapis.avplay.setStreamingProperty('COOKIE', '...');